# 400 - Bad Request ( AngularJS+Passport)

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I use angularJS+passport to perform user authentication and hence, i set up these below.
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="logincontroller">
<form>
Email:<input type="text" ng-model="user.email"/>
Password:<input type="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
<div ng-click=loginUser()>Submit</div>
</form>
</div>
```

In client side javascript:

```
  app.controller('logincontroller',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.loginUser=function(){
    $http.post('/loginUser',JSON.stringify($scope.user));
   }
   })
```

ON app.js

```
   passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField: 'user.email',
    passwordField: 'user.password',
    passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req,username,password,done){
      console.log("am hre");

}
))

app.post('/loginUser',passport.authenticate('local'));
```

I am not sure if i have set request pattern right. I get 400 - Bad request while trying to login and i don't think strategy is invoked. Please favour.

Answer (score 0):

Well,Just had to add name attribute to input tag. That solves it all

In html

```
Email:<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
```

And in app.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req,username,password,done){
      console.log("am hre");
```